# Spivak Calculus chapter 2 question 21 on Schwarz Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> This is the most interesting proof—it depends on the equality $$
>  \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2=\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i  \right) ^2+\sum_{i<j}\left( x_iy_j-x_jy_i \right) ^2  
> .$$ To check this equality, note that,
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2y_i^2 +\sum_{i\neq j}x_i^2y_j^2 \\
> \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i  \right) ^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( x_iy_i \right)  ^2+\sum_{i\neq j}x_iy_ix_jy_j
> \end{align*}
> The difference is
> \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{i\neq j}\left( x_i^2y_j^2-x_iy_ix_jy_j \right) &= 2\sum_{i<j}\left( x_i^2y_j^2+x_j^2y_i^2-x_iy_ix_jy_j \right)  \\
>              &= 2\sum_{i<j}\left( x_iy_j-x_jy_i \right) ^2
> \end{align*}
> If equality holds in the Schwarz inequality, then all $x_iy_j=x_jy_i$. If some $y_i\neq 0$ say $y_1\neq 0$, then $x_i=\frac{x_1}{y_1}y_i$ for all $i$, so we can let $\lambda =\frac{x_1}{y_1}$.

So I got stuck trying to prove the Schwarz inequality by expressing the product of magnitudes as a sum of two squares, and was reading the solution from the answer book; however I could not understand the last part on "the difference", i.e. $ \sum_{i≠j}({x_i}^2{y_j}^2 - x_iy_ix_jy_j) = 2 \sum_{i<j} ({x_i}^2{y_j}^2 + {x_j}^2{y_i}^2 - x_iy_ix_jy_j) $. Please help me understand how the terms doubled and why the next line suddenly had a square term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two typos in this page: On the first line after "The difference...", the "2" should be in front of $x_iy_ix_jy_j$, the reason being that when you change the index from $i\neq j$ to $i<j$ you have to double all the terms: say on the  left hand side you have both $x_1^2y_2^2$ and $x_2^2y_1^2$, and since on the right hand side $I<j$ you have to include the second one. The same applies to the products $x_iy_ix_jy_j$. Each of the terms is obviously a square. There is a typo on the following line: there is no "2" in front of the sum, as in the original (and correct) statement of the inequality.

Comment: I see, so it was two typos at once! That makes much more sense.

Comment: Yes. Two typos at once is very unlikely assuming they follow a Poisson distribution... but in this case the typos are linked to each other so probably it is not safe to assume that for a Math book. Spivak's books are great anyways.