# Generalized Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality proof by induction (Spivak calculus chapter 2 problem 21)

Tags: induction, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In Spivak's calculus problem 2-21 is about proving the generalized Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality using the same three methods used in problem 1-19. The latter (i.e. problem 1-19) is the specific case of the inequality and therefore we can take as a given that:

$x_1y_1+x_2y_2 \le \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2} \sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}$

Now, I've already done the 3 methods for problem 1-19 (you can see the sort of techniques used in [this question about the same problem discussing one of the 3 approaches](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537600/spivak-calculus-chapter-2-question-21-on-schwarz-inequality)).

But Chapter 2 to of the book is all about mathematical induction. So in addition to repeating the same three methods discussed in problem 1-19, I was hoping that this proof would be acceptable as well:

---

For $n=2$ we have proven in Problem 1-19 that:

$
x_1y_1+x_2y_2 \le \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2} \sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2} \quad \text{(1)}
$

Let us assume that it is true for $n = k$ and therefore:

$ \sum_{i=1}^{k}{x_i y_i} \le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}{x_i^2}} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}{y_i^2}} \quad \text{(2)} $

Then for $n=k+1$ we have:

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{x_i y_i} =
x_{k+1}y_{k+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}{x_i y_i} &\le \quad \text{(by (2) from induction hypothesis)} \\
x_{k+1}y_{k+1} + \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}{x_i^2}} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}{y_i^2}} & \le \quad \text{by (1) from problem 1-19} \\
\sqrt{x_{k+1}^2+\left(\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}{x_i^2}}\right)^2 + y_{k+1}^2+\left(\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k}{y_i^2}}\right)^2} = \\
\sqrt{x_{k+1}^2+\sum_{i=1}^{k}{x_i^2} + y_{k+1}^2+\sum_{i=1}^{k}{y_i^2}} = \\
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{x_i^2} + \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}{y_i^2}} \\
\end{aligned}

Is this a perfectly valid use of induction and a correct "4th proof"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We wanted to show that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}x_iy_i \le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}x_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}y_i^2}$$

not

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}x_iy_i \le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}x_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}y_i^2}$$

Hence you have not proven it. Most likely you intend to do the following:

Let $u_k = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2}$ and $v_k = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k y_i^2}$

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}x_iy_i &=x_{k+1}y_{k+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_iy_i \\
& \le x_{k+1}y_{k+1} + \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k y_i^2}\\
&= x_{k+1}y_{k+1}+u_k v_k \\
&= \sqrt{x_{k+1}^2+u_k^2}\sqrt{y_{k+1}^2+v_k^2}\\
&= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}x_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}y_i^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Ahh this was exactly my intention. Thanks.